# PostgreSQL: constraint name is not necessarily unique

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to list all the foreign keys in a schema, and, for each key, listing the columns involved.
So I'm querying the `pg_catalog.pg_constraint` and `information_schema.columns` tables.

I need a way to distinguish the keys, to do the second query and retrieve the key columns list.

I thought to use the constraint name (the `conname` column, in `pg_catalog.pg_constraint` table), but the [PostgreSQL documentation about pg_constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html) says that the constraint name  is not necessarily unique! Why? I can't find additional information about this fact in the documentation.

Is the couple `connamespace` + `conname` unique?

This are my queries:

*Retrieve the lists of foreign keys from and to the given schema:*

```
SELECT
conname AS constraint_name,
conrelid::regclass AS referring_table, 
confrelid::regclass AS referenced_table
FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint
WHERE contype = 'f' AND ((conrelid::regclass || '' LIKE '<my_schema_name>.%') OR (confrelid::regclass || '' LIKE '<my_schema_name>.%'))
```

*Retrieve the list of columns of a given key:*

```
SELECT
c.column_name AS key_column
FROM information_schema.columns c
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_constraint r ON (c.table_schema || '.' || c.table_name) = (r.conrelid::regclass || '')
WHERE r.conname = '<my_constraint_name>'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The logical key seems to be (schemaname, constraint_name): the names are supposed to be unique within a schema. This is not reflected in pg_catalog.pg_constraint, it only has a non-unique index on (conname, connamespace). IMHO there is no need to enforce uniqueness by means of constraints at this level.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Constraint names are unique only within the object on which they are defined.

Two different tables (or domains) can have constraints with the same name.

The exception to that rule are constraints that are implemented by an index (primary key, unique and exclusion constraints). The index that implements the constraint has to have the same name as the constraint, and indexes share a namespace with tables, views, sequences and composite types, which means that no two such objects in the same schema can have the same name.

Comment: Then why this DDL giving error ? "SQL Error [42P07]: ERROR: relation "pk_const" already existsSQL "    --     create table table1 (id varchar(8),name varchar(50),CONSTRAINT pk_const PRIMARY key (id))
 
create table table2 (id varchar(8),name varchar(50),CONSTRAINT pk_const PRIMARY key (id))

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya I have added an explanation. The problem is not the constraint name, but the index name.