# Constraint in a different schema appears to be blocking create table

Tags: postgresql

Got a table called `county`. I'm recreating it as part of a Liquibase migration:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS county;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS county (
    id varchar NOT NULL,  
    "name" varchar NOT NULL,
    state_id varchar NOT NULL, 
    state_abbr varchar NOT NULL,
    state_name varchar NOT NULL,
    country_code varchar NOT NULL,  
    country_name varchar NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT pk_county PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The drop: fine. The create? No: `ERROR: relation "pk_county" already exists`. But the docs say

> DROP TABLE always removes any indexes, rules, triggers, and constraints that exist for the target table. However, to drop a table that is referenced by a view or a foreign-key constraint of another table, CASCADE must be specified. (CASCADE will remove a dependent view entirely, but in the foreign-key case it will only remove the foreign-key constraint, not the other table entirely.)

OK, odd, there's no foreign keys, but I try adding `cascade` anyway. Same result. When I check the info schema:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.constraint_table_usage
WHERE table_name = 'county'
```

I only see one entry and **it's in a different table_schema**. Constraint names are [certainly not required to be globally unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718656/postgresql-constraint-name-is-not-necessarily-unique) (or a lot of things would have broken before this since each dev in this development db has their own schema).

If I rename `pk_county` to `pk_county2` the whole thing works. But that tells me that constraint names are required to be globally unique, which makes no sense.

So how can a constraint be hanging around after a `drop` is called? How do I drop a table and then create it again with a primary key constraint? Something is weird here.

Comment: Could you show us your search path ? And did you try creating the new table using a schema qualification? (something you should imho always do, also for public)

Comment: In `psql` do `select * from pg_class where relname = 'pk_county' and relkind = 'i';`

Comment: Good call, the other dev's schema is in my search path. We are setting the schema outside of this script when we run the deployment.

Comment: @FrankHeikens if you write up an answer involving search path I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Creating a primary key called `pk_county` automatically created a unique index called `pk_county`. Now indexes share a name space with tables, views, sequences, composite data types, foreign tables etc. So there already exists one of these objects with the name `pk_county` in the same schema.

To find out what the conflicting relation is, run

```
SELECT relname,
       relnamespace::regnamespace AS schema_name
       relkind
FROM pg_class
WHERE relname = 'pk_county';
```

Comment: @FrankHeikens got it in a comment: the other dev's schema was in my search path